# Geo Django Subclassing Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, geo, subclassing

I'm using GeoDjango to search for a bunch of locations of different types.  For example, both House and Appartment models are subclasses of Location.

Using the Subclassing Queryset below, I'm able to do something like Location.objects.all() and have it return to me `[<House: myhouse>, <House: yourhouse>, <Appartment: myappartment>]`, which is my desire.

However, I also want to determine the distance to each location.  Normally, without the Subclassing Queryset, the code from Exhibit 2 returns for me the distances from the given point to each location.... `[ (<Location: Location object>, Distance(m=866.092847284))]`

However, if I try to find the distances using the Subclassing Querysets, I get an error such as:

**AttributeError: 'House' object has no attribute 'distance'**

Do you know how I can preserve the ability return a queryset of subclassed objects yet have the distance property available on the subclass objects?   Any advice is much appreciated.

Exhibit 1:

```
class SubclassingQuerySet(models.query.GeoQuerySet):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        result = super(SubclassingQuerySet, self).__getitem__(k)
        if isinstance(result, models.Model) :
            return result.as_leaf_class()
        else :
            return result
    def __iter__(self):
        for item in super(SubclassingQuerySet, self).__iter__():
            yield item.as_leaf_class()

class LocationManager(models.GeoManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return SubclassingQuerySet(self.model)

class Location(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,editable=False,null=True)
    objects = LocationManager()

class House(Location):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = LocationManager()

class Appartment(Location):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = LocationManager()
```

Exhibit 2:

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D 
from django.contrib.gis.geos import fromstr
ref_pnt =  fromstr('POINT(-87.627778 41.881944)')

location_objs = Location.objects.filter(
        point__distance_lte=(ref_pnt, D(m=1000) 
              )).distance(ref_pnt).order_by('distance')
[ (l, l.distance) for l in location_objs.distance(ref_pnt) ]   # <--- errors out here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm busy trying to solve this one to.  How about this:

```
class QuerySetManager(models.GeoManager):
    '''
    Generates a new QuerySet method and extends the original query object manager in the Model
    '''
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(QuerySetManager, self).get_query_set()
```

And the rest can follow from this [DjangoSnippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/734/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to reassign the manager in all subclasses.

From Django documentation:

> Managers defined on non-abstract base classes are not inherited by child classes. If you want to reuse a manager from a non-abstract base, redeclare it explicitly on the child class. These sorts of managers are likely to be fairly specific to the class they are defined on, so inheriting them can often lead to unexpected results (particularly as far as the default manager goes). Therefore, they aren't passed onto child classes.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance